# Select ID on click event jquery

Tags: jquery

I have a div that I can insert words from and input field, user can type the word on the input and save them to display on the div "display_words". 
Now I want to be able to remove selected words from that div and I'm assigning a dynamic ID to those words and it looks like this:

```
 <div id="display_words">
   <div class="clhotpages" id="word1">word1</div>
   <div class="clhotpages" id="word2">word2</div>
 </div>
```

I have a function that I can detect that they click on the class "clhotpages":

```
      $(".clhotpages").live('click', function() {
        //GET ID TO REMOVE THAT WORD
        alert("click");
      });
```

Now I want to be able to let the user remove a word from the div on click event.

But I don't know how to get the ID from the div, because ID's are dynamic.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd suggest:

```
$('#display_words').on('click','div.clhotpages', function(e){
    var id = this.id; // or e.target.id; gets the id
    $(e.target).remove(); // removes the word
});
```

The `on()` method is supported in jQuery 1.7+ (and `live()` is deprecated as of 1.7, and removed as of 1.9). Prior to jQuery 1.7, though, `delegate()` is recommended rather than `live()`.

With `delegate()` the above would be written as:

```
$('#display_words').delegate('div.clhotpages', 'click', function(e){
    var id = this.id; // or e.target.id
    $(e.target).remove();
});
```

References:

- [`delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate).
- [`live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live).
- [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on).

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$("#display_words").on('click', '.clhotpages', function() {
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   alert("click");
});
```

`.live()` has been deprecated in favor of `.on()` and removed entirely in jQuery 1.9. More importantly, when you add elements dynamically you need to bind with on via a delegated element.

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
$(".clhotpages").click(function() {
    var currentID = $(this).attr("id");
    $(this).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`.attr()` function](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to extract specific attributes.

```
$(".clhotpages").live('click', function() {
  $(this).attr('id');
});
```

That being said, you don't really have to extract the `id` in order to remove the element. Within the click callback, you can use the `$(this)` variable to refer to the actual element that was clicked. So you could do something like this -

```
$(".clhotpages").live('click',function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

---

You might also want to use the [`.on()` function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) as a replacement for `.live()`. The `.live()` function is in the process of deprecation. Using `.on()`, your code would look like this:

```
$("#display_words").on('click','.clhotpages',function(){
  $(this).remove();
});
```

> I'm assuming that the `#display_words` element exists when the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $(".clhotpages").click(function(){
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
 });
```